# How to use ActionLink inside Kendo Notification

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with showing @Html.ActionLink inside Kendo Notification.

Everything seems working but i can't get link visible. Here is the script + actionlink code:

```
  notification.show(
                { message: "Onayınızı bekleyen  @ViewBag.Sum konu var. Onay için"@Html.ActionLink("ClickMe", "Action", "Controller") " }
                    , "upload-success");
            }
```

Where is the problem?

Here is my script code:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Notification()
.Name("notification")

.Position(p => p.Pinned(true).Top(30).Right(30))
.Stacking(NotificationStackingSettings.Down)
.AutoHideAfter(60000)
.Templates(t =>
{

    t.Add().Type("wrong-pass").ClientTemplateID("errorTemplate");
    t.Add().Type("upload-success").ClientTemplateID("successTemplate");
})
)
```

My template

```
<script id="successTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div class="upload-success">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="../Images/success-icon.png " /></td>
                <td><h3>#= message #</h3></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</script>
```

My Script code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var a = parseInt(@ViewBag.Sum);

        alert(a);

        var notification = $("#notification").data("kendoNotification");
        if (a >0) {
            notification.show(
                { message: "Onayınızı bekleyen  @ViewBag.Sum konu var. Onay için"@Html.ActionLink("ClickMe", "Action", "Controller") " }
                    , "upload-success");
            }

            else {
                notification.show({
                    message: "Hata Oluştu"
                }, "error");

            }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you done a "view source" to see if the generated JavaScript is correct?  If it is, then you may have a css issue.

Comment: Yep, i can get what i want except @Html.ActionLink. I have just problem with showing links.

Comment: You will have to open up the debugger in browser to see exactly why it is  not being displayed.